# Insurance for skydiving in USA as a UK citizen

Tags: usa, insurance, uk-citizens, parachutes-skydiving

I'm a UK citizen currently living and working in the USA for the duration of this summer.

I'd like to do a tandem skydive in the next few weeks, but my current insurance policy (Post Office Travel) doesn't cover hazardous activities, and after contacting them to see if I could add on to my existing policy they stated that they do not provide cover for skydiving.

I also contacted another company (STA) who do cover skydiving, but they said they were unable to help me since I already left the UK (almost two months ago at this point).

Is there some kind of temporary insurance that I can get so I could be covered for a skydive?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but have you asked the company that's organizing your jump?  I'd think they would have insurers to recommend, and would expect a US insurer would be able to cover you regardless of your citizenship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find an appropriate insurance policy from IMG known as '[Patriot Adventure](http://www.imglobal.com/en/img-insurance/adventure-sports-insurance/patriot-adventure-travel-medical-insurance.aspx)'. They offer insurance to US citizens, non-US citizens, and people who have already left their home country. Shortest possible period is 30 days. Covers a huge list of adventure sports and activities.

Answer (score 4):

I taught sport parachuting for 10 years. Zero personal injuries, but I've seen some good ones.

The place providing tandem jumps might have recommended insurers, but they have none themselves. That lengthy document you will sign in the morning basically says you knew what the risks were.

However, the tandem-jump risks are basically either bumps and bruises from a rough landing or death from a failed system (or instructor). You won't need health care for the former and you won't care after the latter.

Serious but survivable skydiving accidents are typically solo students who don't listen and crash into things like trees, or experienced jumpers who think they are better than they are and crash into things like benches when they try to hot-dog a landing. (That particular person shattered his ankle on a bench and paid the hospital bill on his visa.)

Comment: One thing travel insurance is often used to cover is the cost of repatriation of remains...

Comment: True, but repatriation of remains is of no particular benefit to the insured.